# Freezing keyboard and some functions

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, lenovo, freeze, restart

I'm new in Linux (using Ubuntu Studio 18.04 Bionic Beaver) and I have the following issue: When I start the PC and give it some use, at some point, my keyboard stop working, and some displays too, like the power button or some options as the right-click on the desktop. The "solution" is to restart the PC by hand.

My PC is Lenovo IdeaPad V330; I5-8250U, 12gb RAM, 120gb SSD, 1tb HDD (only for /home).

Edit: 
Memory:         11G        1,9G        8,0G        214M        1,2G        8,7G

Swap:           13G          0B         13G

Bios 6SCN42WW

vm.swappiness = 10

Comment: Do you have swap space defined? `free -h` will show you. I suggest 1.5x RAM size, or 18GB to start. Read `man swapon;man mkswap`

Comment: thanks for replying. i have 13gb swap, may be i have to add some more? i will try that

Comment: @waltinator 18G swap is excessive (as is 13G), unless they hibernate.

Comment: Your swap is excessive (unless you hibernate). Edit your question and show me `free -h` (as requested earlier) and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness`. What applications do you normally run? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema thank you for answer. there is the edit. Normally i use mozilla, ardour, guitarix, but i found that it's not because of the apps, it's kind of randomly. Once that i reset it works normally. Also i updated the software and serch for more actualizations, but it's not that either. Again, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

**Swap...**

- with 11G RAM, vm.swappiness=10 is set way too low

  - temporarily try `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80`
  - we'll make it permanent later if it helps
- your swap partition/swapfile is excessive (unless you hibernate)

  - later we'll consider reducing the size of your swap
  - show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`

**BIOS...**

```
Lenovo IdeaPad V330-15IKB
Bios 6SCN42WW
```

- [This web page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v330-15ikb/downloads/ds501698) indicates that 6SCN48WW (from Jan 12, 2020) is the current version.
- download the newer BIOS, and the update instructions (if there are any)
- backup your important files
- update the BIOS

Comment: thank for this post. You are becoming to be my religion, when i previously install windows, i had some issues whit the bios too, so i gues that it can be a big part of the problem.
.
grep -i swap /etc/fstab :
.
# swap was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=8a62bed5-c651-43b0-9e97-cf8ba85251ab none            swap    sw              0       0

i'm trying to update bios now

Comment: okay new problem. can't install bios.exe. I wanted to try wine to run it, but i can't install wine because "missing dependencies". I dind't found a .iso for the update, that's why i was trying wine. But now i don't know what to do

Comment: Do you have Windows installed? If so, install it from there. Otherwise, did the web site give any specific instructions for installing the BIOS (that don't include the use of Windows)? Otherwise see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqDUCfU-e-A

Comment: after a long and patience process, in the last step i got this message "this program must be run under win32".

Comment: @Debede Did you get that error message when running from the freedos USB stick, or something else? Check your BIOS... some BIOS let you update directly from inside the BIOS itself. Have you had time to try my sysctl command and see if it helps at all?

Comment: yes, when i tried to run the exe from freedos it's when that message appears. okay, i'll  check the bios itself then. I don't know what "my sysctl" is, but i'll google it, thank you, you are amazing. i'll update in a couple of minutes

Comment: @Debede my sysctl refers to the "sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80" shown in the first part of my answer. It's only temporary, but if it helps, I'll expand my answer to include a permanent patch.

Comment: ohh i see, i did that, but felt no changes. And the bios cannot be updated by hand either. May be i should try again with wine, and see if i can run the .exe, what do you say?

Comment: The sysctl command is temporary, and disappears at boot/reboot. After entering the command, use the computer normally and see if your problem symptoms are gone. If they are gone, we'll make the sysctl permanent. For the BIOS, if you have any extra unused space on your HDD, you could install Windows, and you could run that for free for 30 days without licensing it, and then you could do the BIOS update.

Comment: okay, i will try it again the sysctl and push to the limit my pc haha. Yes, surely the most easy way for me will be install windows again and update

Comment: @Debede backup your important Ubuntu files... just in case the Windows installer screws up...

Comment: okay, so it did it again, even with the sysctl, and i think that has something to do with the functions of my laptop, cause it's the second time that happens after y press the volume up key.

Comment: @Debede OK, we'll come back to the sysctl thing later, as your setting is wrong right now. Maybe if we can get the new BIOS in there it'll fix it.

Comment: how are you? sorry to bother you again, but i think that i found the source of the problem. I have de V330 15IKB version (just to make it clear), when i press a few times F3, to volume up, or F2, volume down, a few times or even holding it it crashes, but it's the fix at the same time. I mean, i repeat the same proces that freezes it and it's the fix. It's like pharmakon (? 
i dind't update my bios yet, windows it's a pain in the a**, and i want to try again installing wine properly

Comment: @Debede WINE is pretty much useless IMHO, and it certainly can't be used to update the BIOS. Keep me posted.

Comment: how you doing? i'm going to reinstall ubuntu (updating the bios from windows first) and i'd like to know how to set up my partitions, for optimum my platform. thanks!

Comment: @Debede Please don't reinstall Ubuntu yet. Backup your files, then do the BIOS update first, then run for a while and see if anything has changed. If you make too many changes at once, and it doesn't work, you'll never know what caused it. We can discuss partitions a little later, ok?

Comment: you have a good point, i'm not going to disagree with that. But im using Ubuntu Studio and it's a little bit harder to find support without making a post. Also, when i tried to install windows in my /home partition, i couldn't because the disk wasn't GPT or something like that. That's why i'm considering to migrate to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and start from zero. Anyways, i think that i really found the source of my problem, as i said before, it's something with my function keys. In this lenovo the Fn key is for activate the Fs (F1, F2, etc) in their "natural" way, if u know what i mean haha